# How can I get distinct values of data contained in a column named type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using `Single Table Inheritance` in Rails, and so, I have a column `type`, of type String, and models inheriting from a base model. Now, I would like to get a list of all the models inheriting from the base model. The simplest way, I thought, would be querying the base model table, and getting the distinct values contained in the type column. The thing is, I don't know how to perform this query ... and adding a subclass hook in the base model seems inappropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Model.group(:type).collect(&:type)
```

Comment: Seems to be working, but, the first object in the array is the base model, and it also contains the schema declaration. The second item is the first model inheriting from it ( and it doesn't include the schema ). Why is it different for the first item?

Comment: If I do: `FatherModel.group(:type).map {|e| e[:type]}` it returns the correct data.